# Slow "connecting to data source" in Excel for some users

Tags: sql-server, excel, powerquery, m

I've built an Excel document that connects to an on-prem SQL server and pulls data from a SQL database into Excel using the standard M query connection of  "=Sql.Database("server", "database")"

However, when some users refresh the data they are waiting up to 5 minutes. For me, it takes 15-45 seconds. The delay is always on the "connecting to datasource" part. Once the connection has been made, downloading the data is usually fast.

[image: "connecting to data source"]

This discrepancy in time is repeatable even if we refresh the same data at the same time. I have been able to demonstrate a small improvement in their refresh time by giving them a higher spec laptop (I7 vs I5, 16GB vs 8GB RAM) - but I'm not sure the laptop spec would even cause the difference. The volume of data is very small - a few thousand rows at most for some of the queries. The data refresh speed doesn't correlate with network speed at all.

I have ticked "fast data load" on all queries. The "credentials" supplied in the data source settings are via the user's windows accounts and the privacy setting is "organisational".

[image: connection permissions]

Why is the data load so slow for some users? What can I try to improve it for them?

Comment: Have you unchecked ["Allow data previews to download in the background"?](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Power-Query-Editor-REALLY-SLOW-SQL-SERVER-CONNECTION/m-p/1540625#M631546) Also, does it keep happening after they connect the first time? How many queries do you have, and how many rows are they downloading?

Comment: I've tried unchecking that and have asked the user to re-try. Yep, its still slow even when running subsequent queries. There are 8 queries in total, and total number of rows depends on their selection but generally around 10k. Deliberately very small - all the heavy lifting is done in SQL (partly to avoid problems like this!).

Comment: Have you tried turning the SQL queries into views? If yes, how much time does it take on the SQL side to execute? Also, please post some sample M code.

Comment: The queries themselves are very quick to return data - and generally loading the data in Excel on my laptop is also very quick. The problem is that a couple of users are seeing poorer performance - so I don't think the issue is with the underlying dataset. The bottleneck seems to be when Excel is connecting to the datasource.